# How can I remove a key from an Object, Immutably, except key name is not known until you perform the removal?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know I can use the rest operator to remove a key from an Object, such as

```
const myObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
const { a, ...noA } = myObject;
console.log(noA); // => { b: 2, c: 3 }
```

But what if the key name is not known until run time (For example a randomly generated ID)

```
const myobject = {
  cke503: { Fake: '1' },
  cke502: { Fake: '2' },
  cke501: { Fake: '3' },
};
```

I dont know the ID's until runtime, so I use const id = Object.Keys(myobject)[2] to get 'cke501'

```js
    const id = Object.Keys(myobject)[2] // -> 'cke501'
    const { [id], ...rest } = myobject; // -> This doesn't work
```

Comment: So you want to end up with a variable where you don't know its name?

Comment: This is a contrived example to demonstrate the problem, in reality its a deterministic state. I need a new object so I can return a new state as the old state is immutable.

Comment: @slappy - No, I don't know the value of my variable before runtime so I cant use it in my code, It needs to be computed but I dont know the syntax (If its possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to specify a variable name to put the value into, but variable names can't be dynamic, so you'll have to use syntax very similar to computed properties, `const { [prop]: propVal, ...noA } = myObject;`:

```js
const myObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
const prop = 'a'; // Substitute this with the runtime property calculation
const { [prop]: propVal, ...noA } = myObject;
console.log(noA); // => { b: 2, c: 3 }
console.log(propVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
const myobject = {
    cke503: { Fake: '1' },
    cke502: { Fake: '2' },
    cke501: { Fake: '3' },
};
const id = Object.keys(myobject)[2] // -> 'cke501'
const { ...rest } = myobject;
delete rest[id];
```

Comment: Typo in `Keys` should be `k`

Comment: Yes, I think that would work. I wanted to use the rest operator with a computed property I just didn't know the syntax so have accepted the earlier answer. Thank you for your response though, it too would have worked.